# Item not aligned properly inside row Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to align the icon properly inside row but it still does not properly align.
This is my code below:

```
Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: SuperSportSpacing.largePadding,
                    ),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      child: OptimizedImage(
                        team!.icon != null && team.icon!.isNotEmpty
                            ? team.icon
                            : team_place_holder,
                        imageWidth: 64,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextEllipsis(
                      (team.shortName != null && team.shortName!.isNotEmpty)
                          ? team.shortName
                          : team.name,
                      CustomTheme().getScoreCardTeamTextStyle,
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  //red card display
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 11,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: team.bookingSummary!.map((e) {
                          if (e.count! > 1) {
                            return Row(
                                children: List.generate(e.count!, (index) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
                                child: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio: 2 / 3,
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: e.type ?? Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }));
                          } else {
                            return Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
                              child: AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: 2 / 3,
                                child: Container(
                                  color: e.type ?? Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

The results I am getting
[image]

So the red card is not aligned properly, this happens in all games in my list, I want the red card to be aligned in the same position where the text, name of the team ends. May you please help in what I am doing wrong and how can I achieve this with my code.

Comment: you mean the red card that show in man city row?

Comment: Hi @eamirho3ein, yes the man city row and it other rows too going down. The red card does not display in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Expanded` widget from item's text:

```
TextEllipsis(
    (team.shortName != null && team.shortName!.isNotEmpty)
          ? team.shortName
           : team.name,
     CustomTheme().getScoreCardTeamTextStyle,
     maxLines: 1,
),
```

Although you need to wrap your `card` or `text` code with `padding` widget to add some space between card and text.

Comment: I agree that it probably helps. Although I wonder why it works correctly for Milan in the screenshot

Comment: yeah I wondered to, we should see that part of code too. @lvo

Comment: @eamirho3ein, removing the expanded does not do anything, and the code I posted is for everything because I am using a list from the api so that code where I said  red card display in comment line

Comment: how many card man city has in api response? @SaDev

Comment: @eamirho3ein, it has one red card

Comment: @SaDev could you give some explain about this part of code?team.bookingSummary, why do you use a map and convert it to list?